# Is there a simple solution to some of my mesh not moving with the armature?

Tags: mesh, rigging

I'm making a player model to use in a game and some of my mesh wont move. When I rotate my bones some of the mesh that should move with it won't move with it. I've looked at some solutions, but they were all to complex. Is there a simple solution?

[image]

Comment: hello, have you tried to correct the weight of the forearm in Weight Paint mode?

Comment: by that, do you mean to weight paint the entire arm red?

Comment: select the armature in Object mode, shift select the object, swicth to Weight Paint mode, select the forearm bone, paint the forearm in red. If it doesn't work, please share your file. You say that it's too complex, but you can't avoid that

Comment: How do I share a file with you? I weight painted the entire arm red, but it's like the mesh isn't parented correctly. When I say complex, I mean I found a solution that needs me to parent every part of the mesh to the bone I want to move it with.

Comment: upload here and copy paste the URL it will genetate: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sorry I haven't been online for awhile, I was very busy. When I click on the link, It shows error 404.

Comment: yes it doesn't work anymore, try https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here you go! [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=XSWjeo29" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/XSWjeo29/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why some bugs happen but you should:

- Remove the inner faces
- Select all and <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*
- Apply the *Mirror* modifier
- Apply the scale of the armature
- Parent *With Automatic Weights*
- Make sure that the *Bind to Vertex Groups* option is enabled in the *Armature* modifier.

Comment: Can you give me instructions on doing this? I tried googling it but it didn't work.

Comment: doing what part exactly?

Comment: Removing the inner faces, merge by distance, applying the scale and making sure the bind to vertex groups is enabled.

Comment: in my opinion these are all basics of Blender, maybe you should learn modeling before rigging in order to fix all these problems

Comment: Ok. I'll go through a course, thank you soo much for your help

Comment: To learn both modelling and rigging, maybe follow some tutos by Darrin Lile or Sebastian Lague